# Can't find proper keyboard layout for AZERTY MacBook Air keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, internationalization

I have a MacBook Air 13" Early 2015 and I couldn't find the proper keyboard layout matching its actual keyboard

This is a picture for my keyboard :

[image]

Comment: well, AZERTY is usually French, so start there

Comment: the letters were fine ( like a, k, r, z ...) but the other keys are not the same, I tried all the proposed layouts with the French azerty keyboard but none of them matches my physical keyboard

Comment: Google says it might be [Tamazight (Berber)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) but I have no real way to check

Comment: the problem is that I've tried all of the proposed layouts in the settings. but nothing matched the original keyboard mapping , as well as I Don't think it. is Tamazight

Comment: I found that is Spanish keyboard with azerty mapping, but the only Spanish keyboard on the settings is a qwerty keyboard

Comment: azerty is pretty much limited to French/Belgian & some old "colonies" No-one else uses it.

Comment: [Just went through the list of keyboard localizations from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794), couldn't find a match. It looks like "Spanish / Western Spanish - (E)" with an AZERTY layout.

Comment: What purpose do you need to set the layout identical to the actual keys for? Perhaps it could be accomplished with [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

Comment: thanks for your help, well, I used an app called UKELELE, it helped me creating a new layout from an existing one, and in my case I chose Spanish as my reference , so I've just changed Q, W, A and Z to match an azerty spinach keyboard , and at the end thanks for all your help guys I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help, well, I used an app called UKELELE, it helped me creating a new layout from an existing one, and in my case I chose Spanish as my reference , so I've just changed Q, W, A and Z to match an azerty spinach keyboard , and at the end thanks for all your help guys I appreciate it

Comment: Where did you get this machine?  Someone must have modified the keys from the standard Apple product.

Comment: Is this right? because I bought it from a person' but it was used, not new ??

Comment: To my knowledge Apple has never made a keyboard like that, so I think someone must have moved the keycaps around.